Stopping a button click href from openeing the new webpage
I wonder if there is a way that when i create a button in react i dont want it to open the new page i just want it to act as if it has ?
any ideas ?
Code is
     <div>
        <a href="http://web address/php/navpoi1.php" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">
            <Button>Nav to POI1</Button>
        </a>
    </div>
    </main>


You will have to use the react router, search in youtube for some tutorial in that

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
